# Nuget Content Files in .Net core solution not getting copied when installing through Nuget

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I'm not able to copy the content static files in my .Net core web application project that I added when creating the nuget package using nuget package explorer. Same thing get copied correctly in .Net framework project template but  not in .net core template. I'm using VS 2015 update 3.Am i Missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my snapshot of content file structure.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [nuget blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html) about this, and it just isn't supported at this time.

> Supported Project Types
>
> This feature is only for packages that will be installed to projects that are managed using a project.json file. Currently only two projects types are managed by a project.json.
>
> - UWP apps
> - Portable class libraries
>
> The contentFiles option is **not available for other project types**.

It's really a pity this basic functionality has been excluded from the .net Core projects. Especially because PCL is supported, which is a subset of a .net Core project.

There are quite some issues on GitHub about this, and it's very unclear whether or not this feature is coming back any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. Thats really sad coz I believe many times we do require to package files i.e. templates or supporting files necessary.. Hope they get this functionality soon..Its going to be nightmare for us as we are quite heavily dependent on nuget packaging for our project within organization.

Comment: And to this date this BASIC functionality that WAS available before has NOT YET been restored! This is a hindrance to productivity.

Comment: Does anyone have a good approach around this? I need to install a Nuget package that contains content. The package contains a folder that has many content files into a project that targets .NET Core 2

Comment: It seems it still does not work... Which is pretty bad. It was a useful feature.

Answer (score 6):

It seems it is still not supported. Only way to "hack" it is with MSBuild Targets and Build events.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) documentation:

> **build**
> MSBuild **.targets** and **.props** files   Automatically inserted into
> the project file or project.lock.json (NuGet 3.x+).

So to make it work with any file, e.g.: "config.xml" as Nuget Static Content:

1. Create your XY.nuspec file (as you would normally)
2. Include config.xml into the Nuget: `<file src="config.xml" target="contentFiles\any\any\config.xml" />`
3. Add a new .targets file **XY.targets**
4. Include new XY.targets file into your package to the "build" folder. `<file src="XY.targets" target="build"/>`

**Content of the XY.targets file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ContentFilesPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\contentFiles\any\any\</ContentFilesPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyConfigs" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ContentFilesPath)\config.xml" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)config.xml" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Condition="!Exists('$(ProjectDir)config.xml')"></Copy>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

After packaging and installing the Nuget this MSBuild Target will be part of the Cached package and will run on each build (currently before build).

**Issues with this solution:**

- Added files still linked until you build your solution. During the build paheses (BeforeTargets="") files are copied. Until this files still are just linked!!!
- If you set up your content files to have Build actions and be copied to the Output directory of the project those settings will be lost!

Unfortunately this is the best solution for now.

Comment: Awesome answer! I'm using `Restore` target instead of `PreBuildEvent` to copy the files to the package consumer project, works like a charm.

Comment: I take the `Restore` target statement back, it does not work reliably, seems like it only works when `dotnet  restore` is used or on first build of the project.

Comment: You may include all the properties in the project file instead of using a separate `.nuspec` file when using `dotnet pack`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#project-type-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Some public nuget packages (e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.10.0 or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/) can copy files. I've tried to investigate it (https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter and https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver). But it seems, they have implemented very tricky workaround

Comment: I have run into the same issue, and cannot resolve it. Which is pretty bad. Looking into the linked repos I think NUnit does not copy any static files. Those are .DLLs which is referenced and copied to the build output. However Selenium does something really weird...  I don't know how it works.

Answer (score -3):

After reading this post I came up with a work around.  I created a .Net assembly project and completely emptied it out of all content.  Then I moved the project into the same directory as the project for the .Net Core Web application.  Instead of adding the NuGet package reference from the web application, I add it from the .Net assembly project.  All of the files are correctly copied into the directory and are automatically added to the web project, since they share the same directory.  This solution feels very dirty, but it is allowing me to manage static files with a NuGet package for a .Net Core Web project.

Comment: This does not resolve any problem related to question specific.