# .Net Core Nuget Package - Copy files to package consumer wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I have a .Net Core 2.2 Library project.  All this project contains is a bunch of static files that have the "Build Action" set as Content.

The sole purpose of this projectis to be built into a Nuget package, and for any consumers to have the included contents added to their `wwwroot` folder.

Unfortunately, the files "appear" as if they are there, when looking at Solution Explorer, but they actual path is:

`C:\Users\MyName\.nuget\package\mylib.staticfiles\0.0.1\contentFiles\any\netcoreapp2.2\wwwroot`.

In my lib, I am using the following in the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <PackageVersion>0.0.6</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Having a tough time finding documentation on how this should be done.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a Razor Class Library instead. Then, you can actually embed the static resources in the library itself. They still won't be included in the destination project. (That's for the best though). If the consumer want's to change or modify a static file, they simply create a file with the same name in the same place in their project, and it acts as an override. The problem with your approach here is that any updates to NuGet package will clobber any changes in the project, whereas with an RCL, the consumer remains in control.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is not working. The new way is to link files. Static content and code files used to be were copied to the target project. But it is not supported any more. It is considered "polluting" the project.
There is way to hack it is not perfect but works. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469058/nuget-content-files-in-net-core-solution-not-getting-copied-when-installing-thr/56738870#56738870).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your nuget project root folder create a file named `YourProjectName.targets`  with the following content:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <Target Name="CopyScriptsToProject" BeforeTargets="Build">
      <Message Text="Copying wwwroot to your project.." />  
         <ItemGroup>
            <SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\staticwebassets\**\*.*"/>
         </ItemGroup>
         <Copy 
            SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
            DestinationFiles="@(SourceScripts -> '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
            Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
         />
   </Target> 
</Project>
```

Add the following inside your project file (.cproj):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="YourProjectName.targets" PackagePath="build/YourProgectName.targets" />   
  </ItemGroup>
```

Build and pack your nuget project. Install the nuget into project B. Now build project B and you will find all the files from nuget wwwroot inside your project B wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

Nick, this works really great until I upgraded to .NET 6.

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(442,5): Error : Two assets found targeting the same path with incompatible asset kinds: 
'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\XXXXX\2802.0.0\contentFiles\any\net6.0\wwwroot\brand\css\base.css' with kind 'All'
'D:\a\1\s\XXXXXXX\wwwroot\brand\css\base.css' with kind 'All'
for path 'brand/css/base.css'
```