# FileNotFoundException when the .csproj is referred as Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working on a solution where we have three projects,

1. Configuration Project - This is the .NetStandard project where we have all the service configuration code and we have a json file called config.json(contains external service info).
2. Communication Project - This is the .NetStandard project which will be used to communicate with some external services based on the config.json file. The configuration project is referred as a project here.
3. Restful API - This is a .Net core web api project which will call the Communication project to connect with the external services.

Everything works fine when they are under single solution.

Currently I am doing some refactor work to have these each projects under different repositories and the hierarchy goes like this,

- Configuration project is referred in the Communication Project as the nuget reference and the Communication project is referred as the nuget in the Rest API project.

After doing this, now When I tried to run my Rest service, I am getting the "FileNotFound Exception" thrown by the Communication project because it is not able to find the Config.json file.

I set the CopyToOutputDirectory for the Config.json file in the Configuration project and when it is referred in the Communication project(as nuget), I am seeing the auto-generated Config.json in Communication project.

I am not sure where the issue is. Can someone suggest?

Comment: If you look at the output folder of the api project, do you see the file there? My guess is that you don't. You likely need to make the communication project import and re-export the json file

Comment: I didn't see the file in the Communication folder as well. Since the file is autogenerated when referring the configuration project, i am not able to copy it to output directory

Comment: Read the docs :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files - it's a painful process the first time, I know

Comment: I checked the documentation and nothing helps. It seems the issue is related with this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469058/nuget-content-files-in-net-core-solution-not-getting-copied-when-installing-thr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the below in the .csproj,

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="ContentFiles\**" PackagePath="contentFiles\any\any;content" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" PackageCopyToOutput="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
```